# How Do I record the execution time of running sql statements that are stored in files?

Tags: java, mysql, linux

I am doing something related to TPC-H.

I've got sql statements in several files. I need to execute them and record the execution time like this:

```
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I also need the result sets to see if I got the correct result.
My platform is linux(centOS).

If I do this manually I will type statements like this in mysql:

```
  shell> mysql -u tpch -p
  mysql> use tpch;
  mysql> source /home/liova/download/tpch/queries/Q1.sql;
  mysql> source /home/liova/download/tpch/queries/Q2.sql;
```

Comment: What is your exact problem? Do you need us to write the code to read a file, execute the strings via jdbc and measure the performance?

Comment: @oers, something like that. The file itself is a executable sql statement. Maybe JDBC, maybe java runtime class. I need anything to solve this problem. I've edited my problem to show some more details.

Comment: @eggyal, I think my English is not good enough. That's not what I mean. What I mean is I have the answer to the sql query and I want to check if I have got the correct result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To find the execution time**, you should initialize a date object at the start of the program, and then compare that to another date object at the end of the program. This will give you an integer value of how long it took to execute. Then use this int wherever you need it (e.g. print it to the console, to a file, etc.)

```
Date startDate = new Date();
//Run the rest of the program
Date endDate = new Date();
int msElapsedTime = startDate.getTime() - endDate.getTime();
```

If you do not need to do anything in the Java program related to the  results of your query, you can keep this pretty darn simple using `runtime.exec()` to have mysql execute the queries. The only major drawback here is that you can't print out the resulting number of rows affected:

```
Date startDate = new Date();
runtime.exec("mysql db_name < /home/liova/download/tpch/queries/Q1.sql");
Date endDate = new Date();
int msElapsedTime = startDate.getTime() - endDate.getTime();
```

If you actually need to do something with the results, then `runtime.exec()` will not suffice for you. Read on...

**To read the SQL source**, just read it as a text file. It will be easiest if you have each line of the SQL as a separate SQL query, since otherwise you will have to do some parsing and adjustment. Here is an [example](http://www.abbeyworkshop.com/howto/java/readFile/index.html) of reading a file one line at a time.

**To run the SQL**, use JDBC. Here's a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html) on it. Items 1 through 5 will detail everything you should need for running the sql and using the results (from establishing your sql connection to running the query to processing the resultSet object that comes back). If any of these steps cause you trouble, your best bet is to ask a separate question tailored to the specific problem you are having in the process.

Comment: Actually, I want to find out how long does it take to run the query. So can I just that piece of code between the two definition of dates? Like say "runtime.exec("mysql db_name < /home/liova/download/tpch/queries/Q1.sql")"?

Comment: Yes, that should work as well. If you don't actually need to do anything with the results, using `runtime.exec()` is the better option - keeps things simple.

Answer (score 0):

Check you have the right result.

Option 1 spot test.
Could be something as simple as number of records, or Fred's name should now be Bloggs.

Option 2 
A subtle extension to the above, would be a different query that should get the same result. When I say different I mean different, not re-ordering the columns.

Option 3, my personal favourite.
You have a file that contains the result you expect (csv, xml?) and you compare the result you get with it.

So Test1 runs SQLTest1.sql outputs it in some useful format to SQLTest1.Actual, then you compare it with SQLTest1.Expected.

Once you get an acceptable format for the result files, job is near done and you can bolt in more tests with ease.

Comment: So, is it like JDBC, or runtime.exec()? I don't quite understand. What's your approach?

Comment: JDBC probably. Create a command object, poulate from file. Not sure I'd want the added complication of exec the sql file, and piping the result to something else, then picking that up for compare. I can see some advantages in certain situations for something like that, haven't seen anything to indicate they are needed though.