# Testing DB performance using a Java tool

Tags: java, performance, testing

I am a Java developer, now pulled into a performance testing team to develop a tool for them which tests the performance of the Database. My job is to develop a tool which takes in a set of queries, hits the DB simultaneously(threads) and calculates the average response time.

This tool is being developed as a value addition, to impress the clients and thereby to come out of the red status the project is currently in. My questions are..

1. Would it really be a helpful tool and does using threads to hit it simultaneously give us the actual response time it might take?
2. Any suggestions to improve the above mentioned tool further? For eg adding graphs time vs No of queries
3. Any ideas on other tools that can be developed to test the performance of the DB?

Note: It is an internal tool and I am not concerned about the performance of the DB, I just need to test if it can handle multiple queries without much delay. Also please don't suggest to use existing tools, since we are providing something "extra"

Comment: Performance does not relate only to handle multiple queries. It'll ignore optimizers integrated into DBMS; stored procedures in oracle require SGA memory tuning to run properly (have seen failures only present in production env. due to that)... that tool will give a signal but it's not a full diagnose

Answer (score 1):

You can use jmeter which provides a jdbc sampler.

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request

Regards

Philippe

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly the answer to your question, but rather a recommendation.

I would use some well established database benchmark like TPC-H and run it from Java to 
record results.

I suggest looking into this thread for more info:

[How Do I record the execution time of running sql statements that are stored in files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535341/how-do-i-record-the-execution-time-of-running-sql-statements-that-are-stored-in)